# Convert scientific notation to float after sum() in Bigquery

Tags: sql, formatting, google-bigquery, string-formatting, scientific-notation

I have revenue float values as strings. After performing a simple query like:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(date FROM time) date,
    SUM(CAST(revenue AS FLOAT64)) number
FROM
    `mytable`
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I got this:

```
2019-03-11    3.2172407478999996E8
2019-03-10    2.3065347E7
```

And so on.

The question is - **how to convert these values to float?** I know there are questions of the same kind posted already on stack, but none of them brought me to a proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is already a float, just [`FORMAT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format) it:

```
SELECT FORMAT('%.2f', 3.2172407478999996E8)
-- 321724074.79
```

PS: do not convert to float if revenue is some monetary/financial calculation; use decimal datatype instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you cast to a string, you will get the value:

```
CAST(SUM(revenue) AS string) as number
```

Or `numeric`:

```
CAST(SUM(revenue) AS numeric) as number
```

Comment: Yep, seems like it's been always on the surface

Answer (score 0):

what about `INTEGER` casting

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(date FROM time) date,
    SUM(CAST(revenue AS INTEGER)) number
FROM
    `mytable`
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```